# Issues with loading beans from other bundles in Camel BLueprint DSL in Karaf OSGi

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, aries

I am trying to use Camel(2.18.2) + karaf(4.0.8)+blueprint(Aries) for my migration as suggested by experts.

I have separated files as Routes XML files and Beans XML files. 
RouteXml-> it has only Camel Routes
BeanXml-> it has only beans defines

**Structure::**

```
      Bundle-Conf/OSGI-INF/blueprint/rootCamelContext.xml
      Bundle-A/OSGI-INF/blueprint/RouteContextA.xml
              /OSGI-INF/blueprint/BeansA2.xml
      Bundle-B/OSGI-INF/blueprint/RouteContextB.xml
              /OSGI-INF/blueprint/BeansB2.xml
      karaf/Config/Routes/RoutesA1.xml
      karaf/Config/Routes/RoutesB1.xml 

    rootCamelContext.xml -> it has CamelContext and Has some routes and beans  defined .
    RouteContextA.xml-> it has <RouteContex> with some routes
    RoutesA1.xml-> it has <Routes> with some routes
    BeansA2.xml-> it has <Blueprint> with some beans

    RouteContextB.xml-> it has <RouteContex> with some routes
    RoutesB1.xml-> it has <Routes> with some routes
    BeansB2.xml-> it has <Blueprint> with some beans
```

Now rootCamelContext.xml is loading fine.
But other bundle A and B routes are not loading.

Questions:
1. How to load Routes and Beans from Bundle A and Bundle B ?
2. How to attach bundle A and B routes to rootCamelContext ?

Please help me on how to load beans from other bundles.

I did export all packages from other bundles.

**Update**

I am now getting 
      Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found      in the registry for: customBeanProcessor of type: org.apache.camel.Processor

Even though I exposed this above bean in Bundle-B and its state is Active.

```
      karaf-root()>ls |grep -i custom
      [org.apache.camel.Processor, com.rnd.model.impl.CustomServiceProcessorBase, com.rnd.generic.CustomServiceProcessor]
```

osgi.service.blueprint.compname = customBeanProcessor

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried importing the packages in your Conf bundle as well?

Comment: Also adding the error you get could be helpful. Give command `log:display` inside Karaf.